# Regex that gets only initials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Is there a way to create a regex for initials without using back references?  For example, say I want initials for

> New.York

And the regex to output

> N.Y. (or n.y)

So far I have the following:

```
.\.[a-zA-Z]+
```

This outputs the last the initial of the first word instead of the first initial: `w.y`.

UPDATE**

I'm also assigned the RegExp to variable and using the =~ to test some things.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do a replace (just replace all lower-case letters), instead of a match?

Comment: I'm assigning the RegExp to a variable also

Comment: Why a regex? Seems like splitting and grabbing first letters might be easier.

Comment: @user3465296 Okay, but again, what is your desired outcome? Why can't you use back-references? In short, what's the point? Do you just want to validate a format? Do you just want to get the string "N.Y."? What do you need, really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove all the lowercase letters using gsub function,

```
irb(main):004:0> str = "New.York"
=> "New.York"
irb(main):006:0> str.gsub(/[a-z]+/, "")
=> "N.Y"
```

Comment: +1 I think this is the right answer, based on OP's question as of now.

Answer (score 1):

A ruby way to do this given your input of "New.York" could be:

```
str.split('.').collect { |s| s[0] }.join('.')
```

which would return 'N.Y'

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex and you should only output the groups \1 and \2.

```
([a-zA-Z])[^.]*\.([a-zA-Z]).*?\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mU5oL3/2)

If you want to do a replacement you should use `\1.\2`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the capital letters to dictate the regex match using something like this:

```
[15] pry(main)> str
=> "New.York"
[16] pry(main)> str.scan(/[A-Z]+/).join('.')
=> "N.Y"
```